# Replace a word every N lines with sed between a specific line interval

Tags: sed

I have an input file:

```
Line 1 a
Line 2 b
Line 3 c
Line 4 d
Line 5 e
Line 6 f
Line 7 g
Line 8 h
Line 9 i
Line 10 j
Line 11 k
Line 12 l
Line 13 m
Line 14 n
Line 15 o
Line 16 p
Line 17 q
.
.
.
```

I want to insert with sed in a specific line interval, say between line 3 and line 17 of the file, a word that replaces the last word of each line every 4 lines.

In this case, let's say I want to put a `Z` in line 3 of the file, then line 7 of the file (i.e., 3+4), then line 11 of the file (i.e., 7+4), then line 15 of the file (i.e., 11+4).

Is there a way to do this with sed but just opening only once the file that I want to change?

The expected output would be:

```
Line 1 a
Line 2 b
Line 3 Z
Line 4 d
Line 5 e
Line 6 f
Line 7 Z
Line 8 h
Line 9 i
Line 10 j
Line 11 Z
Line 12 l
Line 13 m
Line 14 n
Line 15 Z
Line 16 p
Line 17 q
.
.
.
```

Comment: Generate the desired lines outside of sed: eg `seq 46 44 180`.  Use that to generate the sed commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have GNU sed, you can use the [`first~step` line addressing](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Numeric-Addresses) form:

```
sed '3,17{3~4s/\S*$/Z/}' infile
```

First, we limit all actions to an address range with `3,17{...}`.

Then, within the curly braces, we run this:

```
3~4s/\S*$/Z/
```

"On line 3 and every 4th line after, replace the last word of the line (`\S*$` – longest sequence of non-space characters) with `Z`".

Answer (score 0):

Using POSIX sed, you can do:

```
sed '3,17{s/[^ ]*$/Z/;n;n;n;}'
```

An alternative could be `awk` which can be made a bit more flexible:

```
awk 'NR==3,NR==17{if (c++%4==0) { $NF="Z" }}1'
```